# Application after leaving background state starts from root activity without calling OnResume method when used memory on device more than 75%

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am working with MVVMCROSS on Xamarin Android technology. I created project where main actvity inherited from MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity like it was done on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenus.Droid demo. 
I have a bug in my MvxActivity, which I call from my HomeViewModel I am using Intent to go to my application permissions :

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent();
intent1.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings);
    PackageInfo info = activity.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(activity.PackageName, 0);
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromParts("package", info.PackageName, null);
    intent1.SetData(uri);
    activity.StartActivity(intent1);
```

But I have a bug when some applications are opened on my Acer Iconia One 10 (more that 75% of memory used) and new intent is started, when I click back, It restored MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity, but not calling on my HomeFragment OnResume method.

Could anyone please give me advice or idea how can I fix than or at least how can I understand what is happening in my program in time when application is returning from background. I read https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/ and know that in that moment activity is supposed be restored from background, but I cannot debug it because debuging mode is stopped on my Acer Iconia One 10 device.

Thank you in advance.
Please let me know if I need to precise something or give more code examples.

Comment: That is standard in the Activity lifecycle, if the system needs more resources (memory) the process *will* be killed. You need to preserve the state in OnPause so when that Activity re-enters OnCreate(), you can re-construct its state. Consult the lifecycle diagram and detailed lifecycle methods: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html You can review logcat to determine if the OS is killing your process, but it sounds like it is. You can try raising your app's priority to have the OS kill other processes first, but that is not a guarantee.

Comment: Thank you, how can I save my MvxFragment (HomeFragment and MenuFragment) in OnSaveInstanceState and then restore them on  OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) method ?

Comment: How can I save my MvxFragment (HomeFragment and MenuFragment) in OnSaveInstanceState and then restore them on  OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) method? Please let me know if you need code samples. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, problem was in one static variable which I didn't reinitialize after Activity recreation.
When I saved it status on OnSaveInstanceState method and then restore on OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) it works perfectly!